# Query on hailstone sequence program in python

Tags: python

Below is the program written for hailstone sequence.

```
count = 0

def hailstone(n):
    """Print the terms of the 'hailstone sequence' from n to 1."""
    assert n > 0
    print(n)
    if n > 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            hailstone(n / 2)
        else:
            hailstone((n * 3) + 1)
    count = count + 1
    return count

hailstone(10)
```

After debugging this program, I see that object referenced by `count` that is part of global frame is not getting incremented within the function object `hailstone`, as per the below observation:

### [image]

Any reason, why `count` does not get incremented?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the incremented  `count` is local to the function. The `count` defined in the first line of the code is in global scope

Either

- Pass it as an argument, i.e. `def hailstone(n,count)` and call it as `hailstone(10,count)`
- Make your `count` global, by having a line, `global count` at the starting of your function

Comment: why Cpython does not recognise that `count` is global?

Comment: @overexchange It is because Py is dynamic scoped

Comment: Dynamic scoped, what does that mean?

Comment: @overexchange Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) You will understand it better. Hopefully it helps clear your doubt :)